# SQL Server 2012 and 2014 memory limits

Tags: sql-server

We're in the process of building a new server with 128GB of RAM.  We would like to utilise as much of this as possible and my understanding is that 2008, 2008R2 and 2012 (all STANDARD) are all limited to 64GB of memory.

This makes me think it is a no-brainer at this point to argue the case for SQL Server 2014 Standard, which Brent has confirmed finally upped the limit to 128GB (https://ozar.me/2014/03/good-news-sql-server-standard-editions-limits/)

However, I find this page from Microsoft (surprise, surprise) very confusing: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff642522.aspx

I expect there is some nuance in the terminology, but it seems to state two conflicting facts.

- SQL Server 2014 Standard and Enterprise supports a maximum of 64 gigabytes of system memory.
  and
- SQL Server Standard edition supports 128 gigabytes of system memory and SQL Server Enterprise supports a maximum of the Operating system maximum.

Which is it?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/cc645993.aspx

Look at "Cross-Box Scale Limits" there you find the right Information (for 2014).

I think standard Edition supports 128GB RAM per Instance. The 64GB Ram Limit is only for Analysis Services and Reporting Services

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, that is sort of implied on the MSDN page under the "Applies To:" section, but being in a different box, with the sentence above being so seemingly 'clear' in it's own right leads to a very confusing page!

Comment: Be aware that the link in the answer meanwhile points to information about SQL 2016 (however it is still the same value of 128G for Std. Ed.)

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2014 Supports 128Gb Ram. SQL 2012 and 2008 Supports 64Gb Ram.

At the following site you can see and compare all limitations of all editions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff642522%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: I am not sure this is the correct reference since it shows a value of 64 GB for SQL 2014 but SQL 2014 allows 128 GB for Std. Ed. - so maybe this is related to support of Reporting / Analysis services...?